# Selenium can't determine ready state

Tags: firefox, selenium, automation, selenium-webdriver, testng

I'm running an automated test in Firefox browser using Selenium Web Driver and TestNG, but I'm encountering this error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.internal.seleniumemulation.WaitForPageToLoad handleSeleneseCommand
WARNING: Cannot determine whether page supports ready state. Abandoning wait.
```

This has only recently been occurring, so I think it might have to do with Firefox updates.  Does anyone know what might be causing this issue?

Comment: I haven't seen this issue.  What FF/Selenium version are you on?

Comment: What FF and selenium version are you on?